# wso2 esb cannot forward request to target server

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I have ESB 4.8.1 running on Windows server. 
I created proxy which forward HTTP requests to IIS application. The end point is defined like below. 
Now ESB can connect to IIS well. 
Then IIS server is restarted, ESB cannot connect to IIS application anymore.

```
<endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="abcServerEndpoint">
    <address uri="@ESB_ABC_SERVER_ENDPOINT@">
        <retryConfig>
          <disabledErrorCodes>101503,101507</disabledErrorCodes>
        </retryConfig>
       <timeout> 
               <duration>300000</duration> 
               <responseAction>fault</responseAction> 
           </timeout> 
           <suspendOnFailure> 
               <errorCodes>-1</errorCodes> 
               <initialDuration>0</initialDuration> 
               <progressionFactor>0.0</progressionFactor> 
               <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration> 
           </suspendOnFailure> 
           <markForSuspension> 
               <errorCodes>-1</errorCodes> 
           </markForSuspension> 
    </address>
</endpoint>
```

The error log is like below
2016-01-20 17:52:08,050 [-] [HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-2]  WARN SourceHandler Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-174
2016-01-20 17:52:09,033 [-] [HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-1]  WARN SourceHandler Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-180
2016-01-20 17:52:09,033 [-] [HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-1]  WARN SourceHandler Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-177

Comment: Could you please share the error log along with the question?

Comment: error log is attached. Only timeout is in the error log and carbon log.

Comment: Have a look there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21327584/wso2-esb-http-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-remote-host

Comment: BTW, if I change "-1" to "101503,101507", then "abcServerEndpoint" is marked as suspended. And ESB can connect to abcServer after it is back for the first 4 times. After I restart abcServer again, then esb cannot connect to abcServer again.

Comment: I have disable http keep alive, and this issue do happens before in my testing environment.

Comment: From log, seems ESB still tries to forward request, like TID: [0] [ESB] [2016-01-20 18:16:02,111]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  To: /services/mm/SystemSettingService/LoadSystemSettings, MessageID: urn:uuid:e6587eec-27c1-4f6f-aaba-a1e67b0af015, Direction: request, Envelope: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><jsonObject></jsonObject></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> WARN SourceHandler Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-174 2016-01-20 17:52:09,033 [-]

The reason for the above WARN log is that the connection between the client (in your scenario IIS server) and the ESB got timeout before ESB sends the response to the client.

By default, this timeout is 60 seconds (the socket timeout of http listener). So ESB takes more than 60 seconds to send a response to IIS server.
Cause for this issue could be due to a slow backend.

As a solution you can increase this socket timeout of passthrough http transport by adding below property to passthru-http.properties file in $ESB_HOME/repository/conf/ directory.

```
http.socket.timeout=120000
```

Hope this information will help you.

Comment: thanks a lot, yes, It is caused by http timeout is too short.